# How do I use browser developer tools to inspect content area height as opposed to inline height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

How do I use the browser developer tools to measure and distinguish the heights of an inline element's *inline box* and its *content area*? It would be able to do things like put a border around both the *inline box* and the *content area*, or add different background colours to each.

### Context

Given some HTML code of an inline element like this, there are multiple heights to consider:

```
<span style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 21px">inline element</span>
```

Here's a diagram of the resulting inline element, with the heights of the various areas pointed out:

[image: Diagram]

a. This is the height of the *content area*, 15px high.

b. This is the height of the *inline box*, 21px high.

c. The grey area is the *content area*.

d. The green area at the bottom is the bottom *half-leading*, and it's 3px high, the result of the calculation of `b.` minus `a.` divided by two.

If you add a border to the `<span>` element, the border is placed around the *content area*, not around the *inline box*. I don't know of a way to put a border round the *inline box*.

```html
<span style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 21px; border: 1px solid black">inline element</span>
```

Note that there are situations in which the *inline box* can actually be smaller than the *content area*.

I'm looking for developer tools that can show the difference between these two things.

Comment: I'm a little confused if your asking for pixel values or the CSS properties. For example, If I measure the pixels on your example, I get 16px inside the box and 18px with the borders.

Comment: _You should get 15px inside the box to match font-size_ Would it depend on the font that is being rendered? See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/56976/) ... both spans have font-size 15px defined but different fonts. They produce different heights

Comment: My measuring tool is taking a screenshot and counting pixels, so that's why I was a little confused. If what you want is pixel perfect (what is actually rendered, 16px) or the virtual value (what SHOULD be, 15px in this case). Let's say if you have a tool that visually counts pixels, would that be okay?

Comment: @zgood You're right. I didn't realise that. Would you know what in the font is causing this?

Comment: @Flimm Different fonts will have different vertical height metrics (called ascender/descender values) defined for their glyphs (kinda like padding on top and bottom of the actual character). Check out this article [here](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) it does a way better job explaining it (and it has pictures!).

Comment: @zgood Thanks, that's a great read. The article even asked for the developer tools that I'm asking for in this SO question! I've deleted my comment as it contained incorrect information.

Comment: @Veehmot Sorry, I didn't see your comment. No, I'm not looking for something that analyses the rendered result to count pixels, I'm looking for something that knows what the browser knows.

Answer (score 0):

While not a definitive solution, I got away before using [Dimensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dimensions/baocaagndhipibgklemoalmkljaimfdj?hl=en) addon. What it does is it draws two lines (one for each axis) from the cursor position, until there's a color change. Then it returns the length of the line. So you don't need to manually measure anything.

In your case, I found 2 of the 4 values you wanted.

- a. You can get the content area (16px in my case, see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676250/how-do-i-use-browser-developer-tools-to-inspect-content-area-height-as-opposed-t#comment86364844_49676250)).
- d. Height between the bottom element and the text (3px).
- Height including borders (not asked in question).

Of course not the final solution for what you are asking but honestly I don't think there's a single solution for that. I will look forward for other answers though.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a great find! I'm sure I'm going to use this tool in the future. Unfortunately, I can't upvote the answer, because I'm looking to know the height of *inline box*, which can't be done using this method, and I would like to know the values the browser is using, regardless of whether a border is rendered or not.